# SSH connection timeout issues frequently on local LAN server, ping works

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

Recently I set up my Raspberry Pi 3 server with Arch Linux in my home, connected to my router at home. But I noticed that ssh connections would often give timeout error and seldomly worked.(`ssh: connect to host ***.**.**.** port 22: Operation timed out`) I can't help but wonder what is causing it. When the ssh gives connection timeouts, I am however still able to ping my machine. The ip address was 192.168.1.**(I reserved fixed IP for that Pi on my router)

The problem does not seem to be resolved by simply restarting my Pi. I took a look at my Pi server's ssh log, and Pi never logged the attempts  where there was a connection timeout. This is the situation on both my Mac and Linux machines. I have no problem whatsover on both machines connecting to the managed servers I rented located in the U.S. though. This also does not seem to only happen after long period of inactivity. Because it often occurs that one second I am able to ssh and get a password prompt, and the next second the ssh client informs me of timeouts.

My setup: both clients are connected to the router wirelessly while Pi is connected with ethernet.

Help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
More info:

I have been able to ssh into my machine pretty consistently with my iPhone's client software Terminus. Also, many times I can have one ssh connection alive on my Mac, and when I try to initiate another same exact request, it gives me timeout errors. So maybe this is not my sshd on the Pi failing? Could this be my router playing the tricks here? (I have a Netgear wireless router) By intercepting my ssh request.

Comment: It sounds like the sshd daemon on the raspi is dying for some reason. I'm unsure why this would happen, but it would explain what you're seeing at least. Do the other logs on the pi show anything of interest?

Comment: @djsmiley2k Also, it appears that I have much more success ssh from my iPhone using an app called 'Terminus'. I seem to be able to log into the server on my phone right when my Mac spits out a timeout error. Do you think this gives us anymore insights? My phone's ssh worked every single time I have tried it.

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe caused by the timeout of the ssh session itself, you can edit your client SSH config file in ~/.ssh/config and add the following line:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

This will send a "null packet" every 120 seconds on your SSH connections to keep them alive.

Comment: I was actually unable to connect to the server at all when I say a timeout error. So it is not that a ssh connection goes dead, it is that a connection cannot be established.

Comment: How you are connected to your home network.